# Is it possible to add CSS based on inserted data?

Tags: php, css

Let's say I have a form like this where the user write a name and a color for that name:

Name: abc

Color: #ff0000

When the user insert those values to a table, it add this on CSS:

```
.abc{
  background: #ff0000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Is it possible to do what I mentioned above with only PHP and CSS or do i need any other language?

Comment: Yes you can do this in almost every language. In PHP you’d use `echo`

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Find a PHP tutorial that suits your learning style, and you'll be able to implement this in no time.

Comment: Instead of entering the RGB color value manually, present a graphical color picker with `<input type="color" name="color">`.

Comment: @Code4R7 i had that in mind already, just wrote the example like that to be easier to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .mycss {background: red;}
    </style>
    <script>
    function changeMyCss(e) {
      let l = document.getElementsByClassName('mycss');
      for (let i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        l[i].style.backgroundColor = e.value;
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="mycss">Example text</p>
    <input type="color" onchange="changeMyCss(this);"></input>
  </body>
</html>
```